# Javamail get all emails form a specific sender

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, pop3

In java I need to get all emails from a specific sender. There are couple of ways to do that as shown here: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/using-javamail-for-searching-e-mail-messages

But I need to have the process to be done on gmail side. It is not fine for me to read all emails and then decide which one I should proceed.

Also in http://alvinalexander.com/java/javamail-multiple-search-terms-pop3-mailbox-yahoo you can search message body which it is great, but what about the sender (FROM part)? How can I filter it?

Also reading all emails each time is not good for our bandwidth (Of course we can mark the last read email and read just all new emails somehow like using UIDFolder)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it myself :)

```
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

SearchTerm sender = new FromTerm(new InternetAddress("from@example.com"));
Message[] messages = inbox.search(sender);

for (int i = 1; i < messages.length; i++) {
    read_message(messages[i]);
}
```

All I needed was to add FromTerm!

Comment: I am getting just three emails with the same code you mentioned above. But there multiple in count more than three. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: You may check the api. The code was working for me and I was fetching the correct amount of results.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use server HW to search emails from specific sender you should use [IMAP command](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/411018/Understanding-the-insides-of-the-IMAP-mail-protoco).
You need ImapClient class and method ExecuteSearch(). [Search IMAP commad](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) for you is

```
SEARCH UNSEEN FROM "somebody@example.org"
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the certain sender mail with the recent mail is this one. This is using the Java Mail.

```
int length = messages.length;
Message message = messages[length-1];
Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
String subject = message.getSubject();
String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();
```