# Javamail get all emails form a specific sender - Stack Overflow

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get all the emails from a specific sender, say from@example.com, with JavaMail

I tried following

```
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

SearchTerm sender = new FromTerm(new InternetAddress("from@example.com"));
Message[] messages = inbox.search(sender);`
```

But it's not giving me any of the mails. As I have multiple emails from such sender.

I know I can do it by reading all the emails from my INBOX first, then searching for such sender using `getFrom()`

```
Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();
```

But it is not feasible.

How should I do this?

Comment: This is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429981/javamail-get-all-emails-form-a-specific-sender

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javamail get all emails form a specific sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429981/javamail-get-all-emails-form-a-specific-sender)

Comment: I already referred it.....trying same concept....but not getting any emails in my messages[] ....what should be the fix for this ?

Comment: Try [FromStringTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/FromStringTerm.html) and see if it makes a difference.  If not, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  Of course, I'm assuming you're using IMAP and not POP3.

Comment: @Bill Shannon.. I know I am learning these things.. Can u please explain what if I use POP3 ??

Comment: The POP3 protocol supports no server-side search.  All the headers for all of the messages will be downloaded to the client and searched there, exactly as you would do yourself.  Still, if you have messages from that sender, I would expect it to work.  Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug)?  That would show whether there really are messages from that sender.

Comment: @Bill Shannon....Its my bad....I was using POP3..Changing it to IMAP worked for me...Thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you please post somewhat detailed answer of not using POP3 in this case..So I can mark it as correct one...Thanks!!

Comment: Done, although it's still curious that the search failed when using POP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POP3 protocol supports no server-side search. All the headers for all of the messages will be downloaded to the client and searched there, exactly as you would do yourself. Still, if you have messages from that sender, I would expect it to work.  The [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) would show whether there really are messages from that sender.

Still the simpler and better solution would be to just switch to IMAP and let the server do the searching.